# How to iterate through object without type complain when using reduce method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert the following data `[{ year: "yyyy" }, { month: "mm" }, { day: "dd" }]` into this `{ year: "yyyy", month: "mm", day: "dd" }`. So in the below code base, I used reduce method, but I'm getting type script error message on `curr`, saying "Type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not an array type or a string type." Also on `acc[key]`, I get another error message "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'" In other IDE, I don't get type error, but get this error on console "TypeError: Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method."
I know there are other ways to manipulate the data such as for loop, but I would like to know how I can get this working using reduce method. https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-glitter-43ql15?file=/src/App.tsx:0-550

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  interface IData {
    day: string;
    month: string;
    year: string;
  }

  let data = [{ year: "yyyy" }, { month: "mm" }, { day: "dd" }];

  const updateData = (): IData => {
    const updatedData = data.reduce((accu, curr: { [x: string]: any }) => {
      for (const [key, val] of curr) {
        accu[key] = val;
      }
      return accu;
    }, {});
    console.log(updatedData);
    return updatedData;
  };

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using `any` in TypeScript defeats the purpose of using TypeScript, because you lose type safety. Best to avoid it whenever possible - then you'll be able to more reliably debug things at compile-time instead of at runtime. Here, the values of the properties are *strings*, so you can use that instead. Or, you could leave out the explicit annotation entirely and TypeScript will infer it just fine on its own.
- While iterating, each object being iterated over is in the `curr` parameter. It's not an array; it's a plain object like `{ year: "yyyy" }`. So, trying to iterate over the object with `for..of` doesn't make sense. Use `Object.entries` to iterate over each key and each value.

  ```
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(curr)) {
  ```
- But the returned object still won't be typed properly. While you could call `.reduce` with a generic to indicate the type of the accumulator, because the accumulator isn't fully constructed until the final iteration, you'd have to use `Partial` - and then you'd have to cast it back to the full `IData` at the end. A problem is that all approaches to iterate over the keys of an object will result in the key being typed as a `string`, even if the object's keys are more specific (like `year | month | day`) - so some sort of casting will be necessary somewhere (or you'll have to explicitly check against every possible key at runtime).

  Rather than wrestling with the typing of `.reduce`, consider just doing:

  ```
  const updateData = () => Object.assign({}, ...data) as IData;
  ```

If you really had to use `.reduce`, it'd look something like:

```
interface IData {
    day: string;
    month: string;
    year: string;
}
let data = [{ year: "yyyy" }, { month: "mm" }, { day: "dd" }] as const;
const updateData = (): IData => {
    const updatedData = data.reduce<Partial<IData>>((accu, curr) => {
        for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(curr)) {
            if (key !== 'year' && key !== 'month' && key !== 'day') {
                throw new Error('Non-matching key found');
            }
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
            accu[key] = val;
        }
        return accu;
    }, {});
    return updatedData as IData;
};
```