# How can I reduce type casting and fix type errors with Object.keys.reduce?

Tags: typescript

I have a react form component that passes the form values into a function that formats all of the values from the form state into the shape needed for the post body.

[Here is a link](https://tsplay.dev/mMpZdN) to the code, specifically the code that transforms the state from the react form component.

Here is an MVP:

```js
export interface OrgAddress {
  line1: string
  postCode: string
  country: string
  city: string
  name: string
  comment: string
}
export type SecurityRole = 'superadmin' | 'protectedadmin' | 'admin' | 'manager'

export interface User {
  id: string
  username: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  securityRole: SecurityRole
  organisationId: Organisation['id']
}

export type OrgAdminUser = Pick<User, 'firstName' | 'lastName' | 'username'>

export interface Organisation {
  id: string
  name: string
  contactNumber: string
  category: string
  registeredCharityNumber: string
  address: OrgAddress
  adminUser: OrgAdminUser
  createdAt: string
  updatedAt: string
}

export type NestedKey = 'address' | 'adminUser'
export interface StatePropObj {
  value: string
  error: string
  nestedKey: NestedKey | boolean
  touched: boolean
  hasError: boolean
}

export interface FormState {
  name: StatePropObj
  registeredCharityNumber: StatePropObj
  contactNumber: StatePropObj
  category: StatePropObj
  address: Address
  adminUser: AdminUser
  isFormValid: boolean
  submitErrors: AxiosError | false
}


export interface Address {
  line1: StatePropObj
  postCode: StatePropObj
  country: StatePropObj
  city: StatePropObj
  name: StatePropObj
  comment: StatePropObj
  nested: boolean
}

export interface AdminUser {
  firstName: StatePropObj
  lastName: StatePropObj
  email: StatePropObj
  nested: boolean
}

const getFormPayload = (formState: FormState) => {
  return Object.keys(formState).reduce((acc, key: keyof typeof formState) => {
    const formStateProp = formState[key]
    if (typeof formStateProp === 'boolean') return acc
    if (formStateProp && 'nested' in formStateProp) {
      acc[key] = Object.keys(formStateProp).reduce(
        (nestedAcc, nestedKey: keyof typeof formStateProp) => {
          const prop = formStateProp[nestedKey]
          if (typeof prop === 'boolean') return nestedAcc
          if ('value' in prop) {
            nestedAcc[nestedKey] = prop.value
            return nestedAcc
          }
          return nestedAcc
        },
        {} as OrgAddress | OrgAdminUser
      )
    }
    if (formStateProp && 'value' in formStateProp) {
      acc[key] = formStateProp.value
    }
    return acc
  }, {} as PostOrgBody)
}
```

I am struggling to remove the existing typescript errors. One major concept I'm not understanding is that my `.reduce` method returns an object shaped as `PostOrgBody`, however I am looping over keys of `FormState`. They have similar keynames but I feel like I'm battling typescript and it doesn't want the accumulator object in reduce to use keys from `FormState` because I am constructing a `PostOrgBody`.

I would appreciate any code snippets, readings, etc to help bridge gap in this knowledge to fix the typescript errors and have a better understanding of what the errors are expressing and how to resolve them.

Comment: ① [Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/2887218). Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details. ② Please consider reducing the code to a [mre] that fits on a single screen. If you don't require something to demonstrate the issue (e.g., `AxiosError`) then you might want to remove it to avoid distractions.

Comment: ③ When I search for "typescript object.keys reduce" I get results that seem to cover the basics, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/52856496 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/74803195. And then there are https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174 for just the `Object.keys` part (in short, objects can have more props than TS knows about) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58981956 for just the `reduce` part (in short, TS lacks higher kinded types to express what reduce does to a type incrementally). If those don't suffice to answer your question, could you [edit] it to distinguish it from those?